# Probability of picking 10 cards from a deck of cards

Tags: probability, card-games

We choose $10$ random cards from a normal deck of cards($52$ cards). What is the probability that we get:
a. $0$ aces
b. maximum $3$ aces
c. at least $1$ ace and at least one face card

That's the problem. I thought that since we're choosing $10$ cards from a deck, the sample space should be 
$$
\binom{10}{52} = \frac{52}{10!(52-10)!} \qquad \text{ (1)}
$$

Then about a. question I thought that basically if $4$ aces are picked we should write $\dfrac{4}{52}\cdot \dfrac{3}{51}\cdot \dfrac{2}{50}\cdot\dfrac{1}{49}$ and then dividing this with (1) and then getting the derived set of this, we get the result..
I really don't know if I'm getting anything right here, so I'm in need of your insight.

Answer (score 1):

You have the size of the sample space correct.  You have counted the possible selections of 10 cards from 52.

For (a) you *wish* to count the selections of 10 cards from 48 non-aces, then divide by the size of the sample space.

---

(What you were doing was counting selections of 4 aces from fifty two-cards.  You don't want to do that.)

Comment: So should it be, 48!/ (48-10)! ?

Comment: @Belf. If you meant $\frac{48!}{10!(48-10)!}$, then yes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant and I got ~41% probability!

Comment: @Belf.  It is approximately that, yes.  $246/595 =0.4\dot{\overline{134453781512605042016806722689075630252100840336}}$.

Comment: It is not unsurprising.  Consider that it is the probability that for the fifty two places in a shuffled deck, all four aces do not occupy any from the top ten. That is that all of them lie *approximately* within the lower four fifths of the deck. $$\dfrac{42}{52}\dfrac{41}{51}\dfrac{40}{50}\dfrac{39}{49}\quad\approx\quad \left(\dfrac 45\right)^4$$

Comment: What do you think the probability of b and c should be approximately? @Graham Kemp